Media Keys no longer working with snap apps after upgrade to Ubuntu 24.04
I want media keys to work on all apps. I am not looking into not using Snap versions of firefox, etc. I prefer the Snap versions. I want media keys to work on all media regardless.
Playing videos on Firefox, music on VLC media player, etc. used to play and pause with the media keys on my keyboard and a little play icon would show up on the task bar, now media keys don't work anymore.
VLC sometimes worked, but that's because for some reason I had both the Snap and Ubuntu versions installed. Probably something that the upgrade did.
The Ubuntu version would work with the media keys but not the snap version. I guess something similar is happening with Firefox.
Now how I get the media keys to work is by playing a video on firefox, search for media player on the desktop search bar and leaving the widget open, pause the video, minimize that window and now all other media on other windows pause and play with the media keys, but the small play icon on the task bar doesn't show up anymore.
How do I get the media keys to work as they used to?

See https://askubuntu.com/q/1399383/124466. For VLC, use sudo snap remove vlc and sudo apt install vlc

Thanks for the quick reply, but I'm fine with Snap Firefox and VLC, they update to the latest version faster. I actually uninstalled the non-snap VLC.
The issue is that media keys are no longer working on Ubuntu 24.04 the way they were working before the upgrade.
The media player widget no longer works automatically. I need to open it manually and when no media is playing or there's nothing on pause, media keys stop working. Then I need to play a video, launch the widget and pause the video to get it to do what it used to do without me doing a thing.
I'd like that functionality back.

Well if it works with the APT app, then it is upto you whether you want to get the latest version faster, or whether you want to have a bug-free system. Snap apps are sandboxed and almost always have such compatibility issues.

This question is similar to: How to install Firefox as a traditional deb package (without snap) in Ubuntu 22.04 or later versions?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Media keys on three different 24.04 systems I tested today work just fine with Snap Firefox and other applications, so this problem is not universal. I would suggest that more diagnosis may be needed rather than leaping to the conclusion that it's a Snap issue. I wonder how your system might be different from the three systems I tested.

I have:
Operating System: Ubuntu Studio 24.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.27.11
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.115.0
Qt Version: 5.15.13
Kernel Version: 6.8.0-45-lowlatency (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 12 × AMD Ryzen 5 5600G with Radeon Graphics
Memory: 30.7 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: NV176
It upgraded from Ubuntu 20 or 22 (I can't remember) a few weeks ago. How do I a diagnosis?
